# Search with Lucene on ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I want do a basique search with lucene,

my structure elasticsearch is: 
[my elasticsearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwA1c.png)

And my code java is :

```
private static final String PANIER_ID_OPERATEUR = "ticket.ventes.differe.panierDiffere.idOperateur";
...
booleanQueryBuilder.add(new TermQuery(new Term(PANIER_ID_OPERATEUR, "50e86400-7861-47b5-aca5-56e9e89b2628")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
...
```

And this doesn't work ...

But when i try:

```
private static final String RESTANTDU_FIELD = "ticket.ventes.differe.restantDu";
...
booleanQueryBuilder.add(new TermQuery(new Term(RESTANTDU_FIELD , "38.89")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
...
```

it works ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please do not post images of source code. Edit your question and put the text in the body of it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I need to add "analyze = Analyze.NO" on my field idOperateur